# Specify a non-standard temporary directory for open() method in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Is there a way to specify a path to use as a temporary directory for the `open()` method (while using `open-uri`)?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Ruby 2.0.0 with RVM - it uses the standard system temp dir (`/tmp`). As I am downloading large files, it takes a while before the file gets pulled off the web and moved into the target directory; also, I do not want to fill the `/tmp` filesystem up.

I know there are other methods of downloading files, some allowing to write data in chunks, I am just asking about the standard `open` method with `open-uri`.

The code I use is:

```
['ftp://example1.com/a.gz', 'ftp://example2.com/b', 'example3.com/somefile'].
  each do |uri|
  thread = Thread.new do
    3.times do 
      File.open(uri.split(/\//)[-1], "wb") do |file|
          file.write open(uri).read
      end
    end
  end

  threads << thread
end
```

(the point of all this is I am to make a script pulling large files out of arbitrary sites as a way of saturating the network link in order to check the throughput).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `OpenURI` source code we can see that it uses `Tempfile`:

```
[...]
io = Tempfile.new('open-uri')
[...]
```

`Tempfile` in order to choose the temporary directory uses `Dir.tmpdir`, which in turn uses the system temporary directory or a directory specified by the environment variable `TMPDIR` (between others). So we can write something like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'fileutils'

d = "#{Dir.home}/.tmp"
Dir.mkdir d
ENV["TMPDIR"] = d
p open("http://www.google.com")
ENV.delete("TMPDIR")
FileUtils.rm_rf d
```

In a single command (**please ensure that `$HOME/.tmp`does not exist and is not used**):

```bash
ruby -ropen-uri -rfileutils -e 'd = "#{Dir.home}/.tmp"; Dir.mkdir d; ENV["TMPDIR"] = d; p open("http://www.google.com"); ENV.delete("TMPDIR"); FileUtils.rm_rf d'
```

It should print something like

```
#<Tempfile:$HOME/.tmp/open-uri20131115-16887-nag9pr>
```

**P.S.** I'm using Ruby 2.1.0 preview, so maybe you have to look at `#{ruby directory}/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb` source in order to understand how `OpenURI` manages the temporary file (but it should be very similar)

Comment: That is quite weird, but I already tried setting the `ENV['TMPDIR']` and the target dir to the same value (so that I could ensure all files are removed on exit or trapped `SIGINT`) and it didn't work, also when inspecting `ENV`s (in a separate session) there was nothing at `TMPDIR`, so I thought it's apparently not the way. Now I am using the same OS and same Ruby in a laptop at home and it works perfectly. Most likely something was wrong with the setup of the machine I was working on. Thanks ;)

Comment: Why can't I just pass a string? It works fine when I use the above example code but not when I do following:   
`ENV["TMPDIR"] = "/whatever/path"`   
`p open("http://www.google.com")`

Answer (score 0):

the question is unclear are you asking about the `open` method of `File` class? 
If so just specify the directory

```
File.open("/your/path/to/new-tmp/#{uri.split(/\//)[-1]}","wb")
```

The `open` method of open-uri just reads out into a `StringIO` using `open(uri,&:read)` returns a `String` neither one of these are stored in temp.

```
require 'open-uri'
open("http://www.google.com/").class
#=> StringIO
open("http://www.google.com/", &:read).class
#=> String
```

Comment: O.O it returns `Tempfile` here: `ruby -ropen-uri -e 'p open("http://www.google.com").class' #=> Tempfile`

Comment: Hmm.. You are correct and it seems Buffer is actually creating this TempFile